# Missing insert query in many-to-many assocations

Tags: java, hibernate, insert, mapping

The problem I have is that Hibernate is not inserting a row in the associating table between two classes.

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Product {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Tag> tags;
    // getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Tag {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The Tag class is a generic class for tagging other entities in my domain. In this case Prodcut. But I want to use it for other ones as well; that's why the Tag class doesn't have any reference to Product or any other class.

The relationship between these two entities is represented by 3 tables in the database, one for Product, one for Tag and the other one is to hold the relationship between these two (the following scripts were generated by Hibernate):

```sql
create table products (id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(255) primary key (id))
create table tags (id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
create table product_tags (product_id bigint not null, tag_id bigint not null, primary key (product_id, tag_id))
alter table product_tags add constraint FK_cwj7fm5pu6f1fxb3tvkksaass foreign key (tag_id) references tags
alter table product_tags add constraint FK_llxxxwkh6khck5jwra336sm3i foreign key (product_id) references products
```

The mapping file for Tag:

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="test.Tag" table="tags">
      <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
         <generator class="identity" />
      </id>
      <property name="name" column="name" type="string" unique="true" />
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The mapping file for Product:

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="test.Product" table="products">
      <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
         <generator class="identity" />
      </id>

      <property name="name" column="name" type="string" />

      <set name="tags" table="product_tags" cascade="save-update">
        <key column="product_id" not-null="true" />
        <many-to-many class="test.Tag">
            <column name="tag_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
      </set>

   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And I'm using it like this:

```java
Product p = new Product("Test");
p.setTags(new HashSet<>());
p.getTags().add(new Tag("tag1"));
dao.save(p);
```

This generates the following SQL statements:

```sql
insert into products (id, name) values (null, ?)
insert into tags (id, name) values (null, ?)
```

As you can see, it lacks the insert in the product_tags table that I defined in the mapping.

I tried changing the inverse value from true to false, and I also tried using different mapping tags, like one-to-many with no success.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks